# How to search for multiple phrases inside a list in Python 2

Tags: python

I am making a sample game. It is a game where a player types something and depending on what they type, something new happens. This is all if-else statements, but I cannot figure out how to search for multiple words inside a phrase instead of making multiple elif statements for the same outcome.

```
def room_1(key):

Key = "False"

if key == "True":
    room1_choice = raw_input("Enter Command > ")

    if "door" in room1_choice:
        print "\nThe door lock clicks, and opens...\n"
        first_hall()

    elif "exit" in room1_choice:
        print "\nThe door lock clicks, and opens...\n"
        first_hall()

    elif "leave" in room1_choice:
        print "\nThe door lock clicks, and opens...\n"
        first_hall()

    elif "lamp" in room1_choice:
        print "\nNot sure what you want to do involving a key and a lamp...\n"
        room_1("True")

    else:
        print "\nUnknown command. This is not that hard...\n"
        room_1("True")

elif key == "False":
    room1_choice = raw_input("Enter Command > ")

    suicide = ['suicide', 'hotline']
    if "tape" in room1_choice:
        print "\nAs you remove the tape, the lamp falls on the ground."
        print "The bottom of the lamp breaks off revealing a key inside.\n"
        tape_removed("first")

    elif "shoot" in room1_choice:
        print "\nNo firearm located. That is dangerous...\n"
        room_1(Key)

    elif "kick" in room1_choice:
        print "\nYou attempt using violence, violence is never the answer.\n"
        room_1(Key)

    elif "lamp" in room1_choice:
        print "\nThe lamp is held to the wall using tape...\n"
        room_1(Key)

    elif "door" in room1_choice:
        print "\nThe door is locked.\n"
        room_1(Key)

    elif "your" in room1_choice:
        print "\nSuicide is never the answer.\n"
        room_1(Key)

    elif any(suicide in s for s in room1_choice):
        print "\nSuicide is never the answer.\n"
        room_1(Key)

    elif "kill" in room1_choice:
        print "\nNo! Killing is bad...\n"
        room_1(Key)

    else:
        print "\nUnknown command. Try something else.\n"
        room_1(Key)

elif key == "ignore":
    ignoring_key()
```

*At line 8 and and 12, I would like to combine these two into one single if statement. I attempted using the "any" function but it still does not work. Thank you so much!*

Comment: why not use a dictionary, something like `{lamp:Not sure what you want to do involving a key and a lamp...}`. Then use the `.get()` method to get the value of your `key` which is the user input

Comment: what happens when a user enters brooms?

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track with the `any` function:

```
if any(d in room1_choice for d in ['door', 'exit', 'leave']):
    print "\nThe door lock clicks, and opens...\n"
    first_hall()
```

Comment: Just curious, what is the difference between 's' and 'd' in the if statement? Is there a difference? Thank you so much! This worked by the way!

Comment: Which 's' do you mean?

Comment: Sometimes, people do the following:

Comment: Ah that is just a temporary variable. You could also name it `foobar`.

Answer (score 2):

For conditions with same result you can use [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) ,for example :

```
if set(['door', 'exit', 'leave']).intersection([room1_choice]):
    print "\nThe door lock clicks, and opens...\n"
    first_hall()
```

Comment: You don't need to call set on room1_choice, that is the point of using `.intersection`, it is also not the same as the OP's code as their code will return True for room in rooms, yours will make `room` into `"d","o","r"`

Comment: I dont need but its better to do it!  and how its not the same as OP's code? if there was any intersection between those sets means that one of that words appears in `room1_choice` then it print the sentence! and call the function!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ahaaan! yeah! i though that `room1_choice`  is a list of word!!! thanks so much for reminding!